# How to write tests for mathematical optimization procedures?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on project where I need to minimize functions by several variables like `func(input_parameters, variable_parameters) -> min(variable_parameters)`.

I use optimizing functions from [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/optimize.html), so minimization process is a grey box: I can see the code on [GitHub](https://github.com/scipy/scipy) and read about used algorithms, but I'd like to think that it's okay and aim to testing of my own project.
Though, particular libraries shouldn't matter in this question.

At the moment I use few approaches:

- Create simple examples and find global/local minima by hand and create test that performs optimization and compares its solution with the right one
- If method needs gradients, compare analytically calculated gradients with their numerical approximation in tests
- For iterative algorithms built upon ones provided by `SciPy` check that sequence of function values is monotonically nonincreasing in tests

Is there a book or an article about testing of mathematical optimization procedures?

P. S. I'm not talking about [Test functions for optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_functions_for_optimization)
, I'm asking about approaches used to test optimization procedure to find bugs faster.

Comment: A very good question. I have been struggling with this for years; what you describe is pretty much what I have done in the past, and I would love to hear other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I find the [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/) library really useful for testing optimisation algorithms in development.

You can set it up to generate random test cases (functions, linear programs, etc) according to some specification. The idea is that you pass these to your algorithm and test for known invariants. For example you could have it throw random problems or subproblems at your algorithm and check that (for example):

- Gradient descent methods produce a series of nonincreasing objectives
- Local search finds a solution with no better neighbours
- Heuristics maintain feasibility

There's a useful PyCon talk [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvwfDdgg93E) explaining the idea of property based testing. It focuses more on testing APIs than algorithms, but I think the ideas transfer. I've found this approach does a pretty good job finding cases of unexpected behaviour as I'm writing a new algorithm.